# Hide the title when playback of the video ends

Tags: youtube-api

```
<iframe src="snip?showinfo=0&controls=0&rel=0"></iframe>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremejevs/zjLgE/). All controls, including the title, are hidden before and during playback, but when the video ends, the title appears, ignoring the `showinfo` setting. Is this the intended behavior?

*Not worth asking another question.* Is it possible to hide the `YouTube` watermark with this setup?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first question, this is the intended behavior. YouTube wants the the person on the other end to click on more videos.

As for the second, what you're looking for is the `modestbranding=1` parameter. Unfortunately you have to use that parameter first and you can't use it with `showinfo=0`. I guess YouTube has to get some type of credit right? There may be a tweak out there or an unlisted parameter. I'll give it a few more shots.

Also here you'll find an [explanation from Brian Glick](http://www.labnol.org/internet/embed-youtube-videos-logoless/19532/) at YouTube for this functionality.

Comment: `YouTube wants the person on the other end to click on more videos` - but related videos are disabled by `rel=0`, it's just the title. Have you seen the fiddle? The watermark is still there, but they show the title as well. What's the point? Regarding the second question - I tried `modestbranding=1`, but, as you mentioned, it has no effect with `showinfo=0` (and not showing the title is more important).

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late, but since this question was never answered...

The title only shows up when you're using the [HTML5 playback](http://youtube.com/html5) if enabled and when the video is embedded via iframe. The Flash playback does not show the title in the end.

You can hide/cover up the title using the [YouTube iFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) with `if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED)`. Be aware though, that YouTube doesn't allow to you to cover up too much. As long as there is a visible (no right-click) link-back to YouTube like the watermark, the logo in the controls or the clickable title, you should be fine.